# Lift - how to get default value of select using WiringUI

Tags: lift

I have an issue with getting default value of select dropdown. 
i have fruits val:

```
 val fruits = List("apple", "banana", "other")
```

and i render a tr with:

```
<tr id={ theLine.guid }>
      <td>
        {
          SHtml.ajaxSelect(fruits, Full(fruits(0)),
            s => {
              mutateLine(theLine.guid) {
                l => Line(l.guid, l.name, s, l.note)
              }
              Noop
            })
        }
      </td>
(...)
```

on page html is rendered correctly with option selected="selected", but when i try to save it to DB i get empty value of fruit. if i change option to 'other' and then i select it back to 'apple', it saves right value.
i add also a println function to addLine to see what values are in this vector, and there is empty value if i dont change fruit option, so i suppose that it is not problem when i process lines to save it to DB.

can you help me with this?

thanks
Gerard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you change your select option, you are not triggering the event that calls your function. The function is bound to `onChange` and that only gets fired when the value changes.

To fix, you could either: Start with an option like "Select a value". This would require the user to change the item, but is the only way to trigger the `onchange`.

If you don't want to do that, you could add a button and add your logic to a button click handler that would get called when submitted. Something like this should help - you'll need to bind it to your output, either inline as you provided, or via [CSS Selectors](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-7.10.html):

```
var selected = Full(fruits(0))
SHtml.ajaxSelect(fruits, selected,
        s => {
          selected = Full(s)
          Noop
        })

SHtml.ajaxSubmit("Submit", () => {
  mutateLine(theLine.guid) {
    l => Line(l.guid, l.name, selected, l.note)
  }
})
```